# References between classes in MVC4 application

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4

I have three classes in my MVC models (country, state and city) as shown below

```
public class Country
{
    public int CountryID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}


public class State
{
    public int StateID { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public virtual Country Country { get; set; }
}


public class City
{
    public int CityID { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public State State { get; set; }
    public City()
    {
        State = new State();
    }
}
```

Here i have no issues while adding a new country to the database since it doesn't have any foreign key references, But when i add a new state, or city it showed a validation error since some feilds were null. So while inserting a new state, i initialized the country object attribute in the state object to its respective country object, but here the problem which i face is, when i insert a new state, its respective country which is already in the data base is added again to the country table resulting in two copies of the same country in the country table. and same issues with respect to city and state. can some one please help me...

THANKS IN ADVANCE

Comment: Why your `State` in `City` is not `virtual`? So that would save you the `State = new State()` in the constructor. And could you show the code where you add the `State` and the `Country` is getting duplicated.

Comment: your table structure is not right